# ExtJS6 : How to keep the Tree scrollbar even when layout:fit?

Tags: extjs6

I have a TreePanel I want to have a vertical scroll:

```
var layerTree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    store: layerStore,
    xtype: 'tree-grid',
    scrollable: true,
    scroll: 'both',
    height: 410,
    width: 300,
    ......
});
```

But it is sharing another panel that I want to keep in the bottom of the container (will show the clicked node details).

My problem is: If I keep the height of the Tree, I have the scroll but it will be fixed and my detail panel will have a lot of space at bottom.

If I remove the fixed height of the tree and set it to `layout:'fit'` and `region:'center'` with my detail panel as `region:'south'` I can have a better distribution but the tree loses its vertical scroll...

How can I solve this?

[image]

**EDIT: The code I can't fiddle (because I'm a noob).**

```
var treeData = '[{"layerAlias":"IBGE","serviceUrl":"","index":0,"description":"Descrição Teste","cls":"","leaf":false,"checked":false,"institute":"","id":"26","text":"IBGE","layerName":"","idNodeParent":0,"originalServiceUrl":""},{"layerAlias":"OSM","serviceUrl":"","index":1,"description":"Descrição Teste","cls":"","leaf":false,"checked":false,"institute":"","id":"27","text":"OSM","layerName":"","idNodeParent":0,"originalServiceUrl":""}]';

Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {

        var layerTree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {

            xtype: 'tree-grid',
            columns: [{
                xtype: 'treecolumn', 
                text: 'Nome',
                dataIndex: 'text',
                flex: 2,
                sortable: true
            }, {
                text: 'Origem',
                dataIndex: 'institute',
                flex: 1,
                sortable: true,
                align: 'left'
            }],     
            rootVisible: false,
            viewConfig: {
                plugins: {
                    ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
                }
            },

            scrollable: true,
            scroll: 'both',
            height: 410,
            width: 300,
            useArrows: true,
            border:false,
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                items: [{
                    text: 'Expandir',

                }, {
                    text: 'Recolher',

                }]
            }],
            listeners: {
                //itemclick: layerTreeItemClick
            }

        });        

        var layerDetailStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.Memory'],
            fields: [{name: 'layerAlias'},{name: 'description'},{name: 'layerName'},{name: 'serviceUrl'},{name: 'institute'} ], 
            proxy: { type: 'memory' }
        });        

        var layerGridDetails = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
            border:false,
            store:layerDetailStore,
            region:'center',

            columns: [{
                cellWrap: true,
                flex: 1,
                sortable: false,
                hideable: false,
                xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                tpl: [
                    '<tpl for=".">',
                            '<div style="float: left; width: 95%; padding:0px;">',
                                '<div style="font-weight:bold;padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;">{layerAlias}</div>',
                                '<div style="font-weight:bold;padding: 0px;">{institute}</div>',
                                '<div style=" padding: 0px;">{layerName}</div>',
                                '<div style=" padding: 0px;">{serviceUrl}</div>',
                                '<div style=" padding: 0px;">{description}</div>',
                            '</div>',
                     '</tpl>'
                    ]
            }],
        });        

        var treePanelHolder = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
            region:'north',

            border:false,

        });        

        Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
            title: 'Layers',
            renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
            layout: 'border',

            height:500,
            width: 300,
            minWidth: 100,
            maxWidth: 300,

            items : [treePanelHolder, layerGridDetails]
        });        



    }
});
```

Comment: And if you don't set a layout property on the tree panel at all? Could you post a fiddle with the problem?

Comment: Well... I have a `layout: 'border'` container and the tree and detail panel. If I don't set any property the tree will lose the scroll because will grow as I expand the nodes. I'll try to fiddle tomorrow (its 22:25 here now)...

Comment: Use some appropriate layout. For example you could make the fixed panel a docked item. Or you could use a vbox layout.

Comment: This container is already part of a big layout. A classic left-center-right-bottom with floatable left. The question is not my layout because any one I choose will fall in same problem: the tree and the detail panel must be in harmony inside a container. The tree at top with variable space and the detail panel at bottom with fixed height. The problem is when the tree have variable height it lose the scroll.

Comment: Try to fiddle it but have no success. I'm a fiddle noob! Will paste the code in my question.

Comment: If you've got a border layout, and the tree panel is in the centre, it will already be sized to fit the centre region - no need for a height, width, or layout on the tree panel. If the tree panel needs more room, it should create the scroll bar automatically.

Comment: @Robert Watkins I've already tied this. The tree not create the scroll bar. I think it must have a fixed height.

Comment: @Robert Watkins you're wright. I may have messed something before. Done some code clean up now and worked as you said. Left panel (container) as `region:'west',  layout: 'border'` and the tree as `region:'center',scrollable: true, scroll: 'both'` and detail panel as `region:'south', height: 150` solved my problem. Pleas put it as an answer.